# How to get the path to an imported node_module from inside the node_module itself?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, filesystems, node-modules

I might be embarking head first into an X/Y problem here, but:

I have a NodeJS package intended to be used as a plugin to a CLI module, call i  Plugin A.

Then I have an importing package, call it CLI.

The plugin needs to know the path to itself, when it's being called by the CLI, i.e.

```js
import * as plugin from 'plugin-a'

await plugin.doSomething();
```

Inside the function `doSomething` I need to know the path to the plugin, i.e. something like `~/cli/node_modules/plugin-a`.

So far, if I am logging anything like `__dirname` or `__filename` from inside the Plugin A, I still get the paths to the working dir of the CLI.

Code in Plugin A:

```js
function doSomething() {
  console.log('__dirname:', __dirname);
  console.log('__filename:', __filename);
}
```

Run from the CLI:

```
__dirname: /Users/foobar/git/apps/cli/dist/cli
__filename: /Users/foobar/git/apps/cli/dist/cli/webpacked_whatever_typescript.index.js
```

I need the path inside the plugin, as I have to move some files to a temporary directory and do some operations on it.

So far, the only workaround I have is either to hardcode a path to `node_modules/plugin-a` that I just hope to be true, though I find it fragile. The name could change, there could be multiple node-module paths, etc.

Another is to keep all the file contents in memory in NodeJS and write them directly to temporary files, also sub-optimal.

Is there another way?

Thanks in advance.